# Best practice to #create an instance of Class2 and call logic on it from Class1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope, routes

`QuoteRequest` has_one `Quote` belonging_to `QuoteRequest`. Below are the tasks that I'm trying to achieve in my rails app:

1. After `QuoteRequestsController#create` `.save`s it calls `QuotesController#create` (skipping QuotesController#new because there is no view or user input required to create Quote, just an internal scrape task).
2. Within `QuotesController#create` a `Quote.new` instance has `Quote#gather_quote` method called on it
3. `Quote.gather_quote goes on a Watir crawl and saves values to instance variables, this successfullly crawls and saves the desired values to instance variables as tested in console.
4. Then `Quote.save` saves the instance and it's Watir, Quote#gather_quote, collected instance variables to the db. Correct columns are present in the db.

But I am having trouble with, I think, variable passing/scope and or moving from `QuoteRequestController#create` action to `QuoteController#create`  somewhere in my code.

- QuoteRequest instances are saving fine.
- Quote instances are saving, but without the instance variables create by Quote#gather_quote. I don't think the code is even getting to run the Quote.gather_quote method.

Can you help me out with:

a) finding out what's not working with current approach and

b) advising on a nicer way of achieving what I'm trying to if you think there is one.

Thank you.

quote_requests_controller.rb

```
class QuoteRequestsController < ApplicationController
before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [ :new, :create, :show, :index ]

  def new
    @company = current_user.company
    @quote_request = QuoteRequest.new
  end

  def create
    @company = current_user.company
    @quote_request = @company.quote_requests.build(quote_request_params)
    if @quote_request.save
      Quote.create({ quote_request_id: @quote_request.id} )
      render :nothing => true
    end
  end
end
```

quote_request.rb

```
class QuoteRequest < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :company
    has_one :quote
end
```

quote_controller.rb

```
class QuotesController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @quote = Quote.new({ quote_request_id: @quote_request.id })
    @quote.get_quote

    if @quote.save
      render 'show'
    end
  end

  def show
    render 'show'
  end
end
```

quote.rb

```
class Quote < ApplicationRecord
  require 'watir'
  attr_accessor :lives, :salary, :frequency
  attr_reader :url, :username, :password
  belongs_to :quote_request

  def initialize(args)
    @url = 'url' #required by Watir as part of the #gather_quote
    @username = 'me'
    @password = 'password'
    super
  end


  def gather_quote
    browser_session
    login
    start_quote
    complete_form
    scrape_results
  end
end
```

Comment: You're trying to call a controller method from another controller?

Comment: Excuse amater'ness!  In create of one controller (QuoteRequest) I'm wanting to create that object then head over to another controller (Quote) to a)  builld a new instance of this second (Quote) class , then b) run some crawl logic on this new second class instance, then c) save that second classes instance. (And no view rendered by first controller's #create, just carry out a), b) and c) above then second controller renders #show).

Comment: What exactly are you 'crawling'?

Comment: An external site without API, all of that logic works just fine when playing in console. The issue is with the way I am trying to 'new up' a different classes instance after if .save from within the first class, then move to secong classes controller and run logic on this new second class instance, then .save that new second classes instance.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a fundamentally flawed understanding of what a controller is.

A controller is simply a mechanisms for handling a single request-response cycle. Within a single request-response cycle, you don't "head over" to other controllers. And you don't call controllers from other controllers. It just doesn't work that way.

Further, controllers are not tightly coupled with models. That is, you can work with (instantiate, update, save, etc.) the `Quote` model from the `QuoteRequestController`.

To orchestrate activities across multiple model classes (and do stuff like crawling external sites), you should look at plain old ruby objects (sometimes referred to as POROs). Specifically, google around on service objects and the service pattern.

Finally, I don't know how long your crawling takes, but if it's a material amount of time, you may need to look at background jobs (either to avoid request timeouts and/or a crap user experience).

Comment: Thanks for the reality check with my understanding of controllers & MVC and I'll heed your advice re., researching POROs service objects and related patterns. I think part of my issue is the fact that I've split QuoteRequest apart from a Quote (perhaps better named; QuoteResponse), the 'crawl' currently happens inside Quote, anticipated refactoring later, and this has prompted my 'cross controller' attempted creatiions. Anyway, I'll get this refactored and organised properly and then post working code back to this Q.